# Did you know that we have flyers?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So, I talked to our wonderful and amazing designer, [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), and he was kind enough to whip up a flyer for me to post up here so that you all can use it!

Check it out:

[image: diy flyer preview]
([Full size here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37817961/flyer_diy.pdf).)

These are European A4 sized, which print nicely on North American paper sizes as well. You'll need Adobe Reader to open these up.

***If you have feedback, feel free to let me know!*** These aren't exactly carved in stone.

Otherwise, print 'em out, tack 'em on board, talk 'em up. Some grassroots promotion can't hurt.

Comment: Dork that I am, I kind of love the DIY flyer. Just saying. I came up with the copy myself, so if it's hokey then blame me alone. Also, it's taken from our top tags, hence the weird range of topics.

Comment: Too much INK!!! With ink prices between $4,000 - $8,000 / gallon, would it be possible to make a less ink intensive version?

Comment: Yikes, @Tester101 that is expensive. Let me ask Jin!